# Автоматическое включение двусторонней печати при подключении принтера по USB

Tags: печать, hp

По работе периодически приходится проверять принтеры на качество печати.
Алгоритм проверки:

1. Подключение принтера по USB кабелю к компьютеру;
2. В "Устройства и принтеры" на Windows 10 в свойствах принтера включается двусторонняя печать;
3. Печать документа при помощи двусторонней печати в Word.

Я хочу автоматизировать каким-либо образом второй шаг т.к. за раз проверяется больше 20 принтеров и каждый раз включать в свойствах двустороннюю печать на новом принтере выбешивает. Принтеры все одинаковые - старые HP 2055

Comment: Для проверки кач-ва печати включать двустороннюю печать? Это все равно, что спектрометром на мягкость проверять. Зачем такое?

Comment: требование компании. Мажет/Не мажет